# Top Horizontal Navbar with 3 levels of hierarchy

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone help me with the top navbar. Im trying to make a dropdown menu that goes down 3 levels. I have 2 levels already and my third level is messing up. I tried doing it the same way as 2 level but it doesn't work. Thanks!

Here is JsBin https://jsbin.com/harukif/edit

Part of CSS:

```
li a:hover {
  background-color: #c0b283;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #c0b283;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.content{
  margin-top:75px;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML Markup is a bit messed up. Try to achieve the navigation levels with nested lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use for the third level a `div` that is `absolute` positioned with:

```
top: 0;
left: 100%;
```

This will cause that the third menu will appear on the right side of the current hovered element of the second menu.

Here how it looks like in your code - https://jsbin.com/cizoxagubu/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

From my experience:

- `<h3>` tags should probably only wrap directly around text or maybe spans.
- You have inline styling on your `<img>`, you can move that to topNav.css
- Your content should be inside body, including `<h1>`
- You should only put `<li>` inside `<ul>`, you can put other stuff inside `<li>`
- Try not to use `<a href="#">` to hold non-link content
- Float is a totally valid way of doing things, but if you learn flexbox it's more logical, more powerful, produces neater results and responds better on all devices.

The trick to good CSS is clean HTML.

Try this: https://jsbin.com/wahegoc/2/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Credit to @govInda for the right hovering sub menu hierachy

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution, please let me know if it works.

```
.topnav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  z-index: 10;
}

.topmenu {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.topmenu a {
  display: block;
  color: #424242;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #c0b283;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #c0b283;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}
.dropdown-content .dropdown-content {
  left: 100%;
 position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown > .dropdown-content a:hover +  .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.content{
  margin-top:75px;
}
```

Check the jsbin: https://jsbin.com/sefikaqiyo/edit?html,css,js,output

please hover: content and then hover country examples

Comment: When i hover to "Australia" and "Country Examples" the dropdown menu is gone.

Comment: For that your require js my friend. pure css solution is not possible.